# Is there a fluent library for msbuild

Tags: msbuild

So I'm on a new project and once again I'm consuming an inordinate about of time wrestling the msbuild xml.

So, I've got to ask, "Why can't I do this in .net code instead of friggin xml?"

Maybe I should be doing it in powershell but I barely know how to spell that.

Can anyone point me to a fluent library for msbuild or a powershell script that that has examples of the more common build, configure, deploy tasks?

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran across fluent-build here http://code.google.com/p/fluent-build/

Seems like it might work but it looks like he's had some difficulty with cruise control which is the ci server we're using...

If that doesn't work I might try using a fluent xml library to build my build file to make it more maintainable and readable.  Something like http://improve.dk/archive/2007/10/20/xmldocument-fluent-interface.aspx looks interesting.

Comment: I am the author of Fluent Build. You can have it work with Cruise Control by just calling the raw EXE but it is not the level of integration I would like. It is on my roadmap to build it (or maybe a contributor would like too...)